# Installing refinery cms 2.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I add in my gem file

```
gem 'refinerycms', '~> 2.1.3'
```

and after I run bundle install which fails with the following error

```
 Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
 installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
 users on this machine.
 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
 Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
 Resolving dependencies...
 **Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass-rails":**
 In Gemfile:
    refinerycms (~> 2.1.3) x86-mingw32 depends on
      refinerycms-core (= 2.1.3) x86-mingw32 depends on
        sass-rails (~> 3.2.3) x86-mingw32

 sass-rails (4.0.3)
```

but when I add, gem without version

```
gem 'refinerycms'
```

it works. how can I solve this problem to add latests verssion of refinery cms for my existing project.

Comment: Run bundler as your own user not as root. (Don't use sudo).

Comment: It looks like the version that gets installed is refinerycms (0.9.7.15). That's the version it can resolve without dependency issues.

Comment: If I do not write version, it installs this verssion 0.9.7.15. how I can solve this?

Comment: There is problem of version conflicts in my opinion

Comment: What version of Rails (and Ruby) do you run? We run Refinery 2.1.0 on our app with Rails 3.2 with no issues installing or updating. However, from the output above, it looks like you have sass-rails 4.0.3 but refinery wants 3.2.3.